# startswith() function not working in while loop but works in for loop? python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, startswith

not working while-loop

```
i=0

l1=["rohan","sachin","sam","raj"]

while i<len(l1):

    if l1[i].startswith('s'):  #if i comment out  this line it is working 

        print("GREET "+l1[i])

        i=i+1
```

Comment: do you really mean to increment `i` in the `if` block?

Comment: It looks like an endless loop. Shift the last line one tab to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation is important in Python.

You must increment your counter `i` every time, not just when you print, otherwise it's an endless loop.

```
i=0

l1=["rohan","sachin","sam","raj"]

while i<len(l1):

    if l1[i].startswith('s'): 

        print("GREET "+l1[i])

    i=i+1 # <- increment counter outside of if-block!
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because incrementing of i is done inside if condition instead of while loop. As first word in your list did not start with "S" it wont go inside if hence i is not incremented and while loop executes forever. it is just a logic issue

Answer (score 0):

yes ,after shifting counter to left it is working. counter should be placed out side of if block.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Use an code example with references when you provide an answer to help illustrate the answer best.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).